# How can I force Xcode to respect Git insteadOf for dependencies?

Tags: swift, xcode

#### Issue

I'm relatively new to Swift and am trying to write a library that depends on PromiseKit and Starscream. This is my first time trying to use SwiftPM instead of a third-party PM.

If I use this installation pattern ...

```swift
dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream.git", from : "4.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit", from: "6.8.0")
]
```

... I am thrown `The operation couldn’t be completed. (SwiftPM.SPMRepositoryError error 5.)`

If I switch this to the ssh url pattern, I can get the top level packages. But, then the submodules of PromiseKit fail because they are are included in PromiseKit with `https://..`.

```swift
dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
        .package(url: "git@github.com:daltoniam/Starscream.git", from : "4.0.0"),
        .package(url: "git@github.com:mxcl/PromiseKit", from: "6.8.0")
]
```

#### Environment

- My XCode GitHub account is set to clone using ssh.
- My local and global `.gitconfigs` have the the following insteadOf expression:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

#### Question

It seems Xcode is simply ignoring this. What can I do? Using an access token has also failed me to this point.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `insteadOf` git config, but is there a specific reason you're trying to access this using ssh instead of plain ol' https?

Comment: @Alexander Hi, again haha! Xcode seems to be fumbling my GitHub access token. I can't get it to work nor even produce an understable error. At least with this, I can tell what it's doing wrong. Note: I can `swift build` and things are just fine. But, then I don't get any of that nice linting, highlighting, or suggesting in xcode.

Comment: I don't quite follow. These are publicly accessible packages; what does a GitHub access token have to do with this?

Comment: @Alexander I'm in the same boat. I don't really understand why xcode is trying to authenticate when fetching the packages, but it seems to be.

Comment: @Alexander I've also tried removing the `insteadOf`. But, that hasn't helped either.

Answer (score 7):

it seems that xcode has own (embedded?) git which does not care about local/global configs. you can tell XCode to use system git instead :

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM YES
```

then restart xcode to pick setting.
note:I think your git config should be set globally (not per project) to resolve dependencies.